# Testing functions concerning the user object with Django

Tags: django, authentication, testing

I am writing some tests for my Django project, and I am trying to test the login functions and the functions that will be in the "user_passes_test" decorator, in this particular test a function called "is_teacher". Unfortunately, I am not quite sure how to get the user object from the response. What I tried is the following, but I only get the error that the "'dict' object has no attribute 'user'".

```
user = User.objects.create_user(
    first_name='Elmar',
    last_name='Fudd',
    username='ef123',
    email='e.fudd@acme.edu',
    password='rabbitseason'
)
self.client.login(
    username='elmar', password='rabbitseason')
response = self.client.get('/')
request = response.request
self.assertTrue(is_teacher(request.user))
```

How can I get the logged in user from the response?

Comment: what did you use to create your user? are you sure you have his entry in your database? Did you use fixtures? or what?

Comment: Have added the part where I create the user to the part above. Thanks for looking at it!

Comment: Assuming that you are using the default Django User Model, you have to set the password when you create the user, because is encrypted. Take a look at this link... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/tools/#django.test.Client.login

Comment: I do - I use the create_user method that encrypts the password automatically (as it says in the link you provided)

Comment: I see, try to create the user in your setUp class... Like here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/testing/advanced/#example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in Django documentation:

> Recall that middleware are not supported. You can simulate a logged-in
>   user by setting request.user manually.

So basically you have to manually assign the user to the request:

```
request.user = user
```

Where user is your manually created user model.